# Htaccess rewrite one file to another one - coexistence with general rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

In my htaccess file I have:

```
# 1) Redirect all non-www to www

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.mydomain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301] 


# 2) Redirect all files in the root to equivalent files in the subfolder
#    at the same time changing all htm extension to html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ /new/$1.html [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/new/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /new/$1 [L]
```

Now I need to add a rewrite condition for a specific file. 
I will get requests of the type:
http://www.mydomain.com/downloads/myfile1.zip

and I need to rewrite to:
http://www.mydomain.com/new/downloads/myfile2.zip

can you tell me which rule to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert a new rule for zip file handling and then add exception for zip file in subsequent rules:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.mydomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/$1 [L,R=301] 

RewriteRule ^downloads/myfile1\.zip$ /new/downloads/myfile2.zip [L,NC,R=301]

# 2) Redirect all files in the root to equivalent files in the subfolder
#    at the same time changing all htm extension to html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(new/|myfile2\.zip) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.htm$ /new/$1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(new/|myfile2\.zip) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /new/$1 [L]
```

Comment: Sorry I tried your solution, but it seems it's not working, maybe I did a mistake in adapting to my real case. The file zip are not in the root folder they are in the downloads subfolder of the root (old file) and in the downloads subfolder of the new subfolder (new files)